What is the actual law/ requirement for dual citizenship for Ukraine?
I posted this question originally in StackTravel, but was recommended to move it to Law.
I've been trying to find out what is the actual law for the dual citizenship in Ukraine these days?
I've heard there has been a law years ago that once you acquired other citizenship, your Ukrainian one is lost automatically. Then, it seems like this law was amended, and now it is just not recognized.
I've done some research and found that apparently Ukraine doesn't recognize other citizenship, but there is no law that makes it illegal. Apparently, they just treat you as a Ukrainian citizen, and that's all.
I've been told by others that they entered Ukraine on totally foreign passports (UK for example) with no problem. I've been told of instances where border control simply demanded a Ukrainian passport when shown the passport of some other country.
The US embassy in Ukraine told me they had instances of American passports taken out and charged with violation of administrative law (even there is not such a law apparently...). I've done so much research but still don't know what is the actual situation.
I am a Ukrainian with a Ukrainian passport and a US passport and trying to travel to Ukraine in next few months for the first time since I got naturalized in US. I am planning to travel on a Ukrainian passport, but on the way back, there's no way to hide that I also have US passport as I will have to show it to the airline in order to prove I have an entry to US.
Law-wise, is that going to be a problem?

Originally asked on Travel SE.

Don't travel to Ukraine unless you're planning on joining the Ukrainian army. They are desperate for soldiers, so they won't allow you to leave until the conflict has concluded, and will likely draft you if you haven't volunteered.

@nick012000 I am a female. I am not planning to join the Ukrainian army, and I don't think they will force me to join either.

@TanyaKryvoruchenko IIRC they're drafting women along with the elderly and the intellectually disabled. It's your life to risk, though.


I am a Ukrainian with a Ukrainian passport and a US passport and trying to travel to Ukraine in next few months for the first time since I got naturalized in US.

As per Article 19(1) of the citizenship law of Ukraine (translated):

The grounds for losing Ukrainian citizenship are:

voluntary acquisition by a citizen of Ukraine of the citizenship of another state, if at the time of such acquisition he has reached the age of majority.

Voluntary acquisition of citizenship of another state is considered to be all cases when a citizen of Ukraine, in order to acquire citizenship of another state, had to apply for such acquisition in accordance with the procedure established by the national legislation of the state whose citizenship was acquired.
The following cases are not considered voluntary acquisition of another citizenship:
a) simultaneous acquisition of the citizenship of Ukraine and the citizenship of another state or states by a child by birth;
b) a child who is a citizen of Ukraine acquires the citizenship of his adoptive parents as a result of his adoption by foreigners;
c) automatic acquisition by a citizen of Ukraine of another citizenship due to marriage with a foreigner;
d) automatic acquisition of another citizenship by a citizen of Ukraine who has reached the age of majority as a result of the application of the legislation on citizenship of a foreign state, if such a citizen of Ukraine has not received a document confirming that he has the citizenship of another state;

So, whether or not you are still a citizen of Ukraine depends on how exactly you "got naturalized in US".
Practically though, unless the Ukrainian authorities got notified of your US citizenship and cancelled your Ukrainian passport, technically it will still be valid.

on the way back, there's no way to hide that I also have US passport as I will have to show it to the airline in order to prove I have an entry to US

You possibly could show your US passport to the airline only, and your Ukrainian passport to the border control. But whether or not this is a good idea is better asked on Travel SE.

Travel SE has an extensive Q&A about how to travel when you have dual passports.  However, the accepted answer there doesn't actually consider a situation where one might want to visit a country where one has citizenship without actually revealing that citizenship, as one might want to do with Ukraine.

When I recently called Ukrainian Consulate they told me that regardless of me owning US passport, to them I am still a Ukrainian citizen. They told me I could still renew my Ukrainian passport (with which to travel) even though I got naturalized as US citizen.  They told me they cannot force a Ukrainian citizen to revoke their Ukrainian nationality. This is done only volunteerely. However, they didn't say what trouble US passport can cause me during travel. I for sure canno use it to enter Ukraine, as they said, but I still don' tknow if I will be fined, etc. if they discover my US passport.

@TanyaKryvoruchenko Well, laws aren't necessarily applied or even known. The question here is what the law is, not what will happen.
